# Rails 3 Nested form with select boxes with just one set of fields

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, drop-down-menu

this is my first time posting so please let me know if there is anything I need to add. I have an Event resource and a nested Item resource (The function is to allow guests of an event to bring items).

I have a nested Item update form in the Event edit view, that allows you to choose an item from a dropdown select box, and then choose a quantity from another select box to update the # of items needed. This is the form_for below:

```
= form_for @event do |f|
    = f.fields_for :items do |i|
        %p
        = i.select(:name, options_for_select(@event.items.map {|p| p.name}))
        = i.select(:quantity, (1..5))
    = f.submit
```

My issue is that because :items is plural, I get a select boxes for EACH item associated to the event, when I only want one 'item name' select box and one 'item quantity' select box.

When I change the form to :item I get the view I want, but when I hit the 'Update Event' button I get an unknown attribute error for 'item'.

Please let me know what other information might help solve this. I feel like this should be simple, and I have searched a lot for this. Maybe my combination of search terms weren't ideal.

Thanks so much in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is my Event update action:

```
def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:notice] = "Items Updated!"
    else
        redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

**EDIT 2**

Event and Item models with relevant sections only:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :items_attributes, :item_attributes, :name, :item 
 has_many :items
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, :quantity, :event_id
 belongs_to :event
end
```

Edit Action of Event Controller (relevant parts only):

```
    def edit
     @event = Event.find(params[:id])
     @item = @event.items.build
     unauthorized! if cannot? :update, @event
    end
```

Comment: can you show your update action code?

Comment: @rb512 I added the Event update action code above

Comment: can you also show your event and item models with edit action of events controller?

Comment: @rb512 I showed the relevant sections above. Are the Item controller's Edit and Update sections involved in this functionality as well? I don't think so since Item is a nested resource and the Update form_for is for the Event model.

Comment: nope, what you have here is enough

Comment: why do you create new item in your edit action?  At this point you'll already have some items to edit right?

Comment: the new item in the event edit action is for a new item to be added to the event (new/create sequence). After the event owner adds items, the guests can then edit/update the items by filling out the above form with select boxes in order to say they are bringing the items.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your edit action, your variable name is `@item` but in your form it's `:items`.  You also have a field called item in your Event model.  So, in your form, it should be :item and not :items.

But that would still conflict with your item field in Events model.  So to fix this, rename your item variable in the edit action to something like `my_items` and use the same variable in your form.

Calling `items` is a bad idea since rails will confuse it with the items object of `@event`, thereby giving you undesired result.